# How do you set a query timeout for MS SQL using SqlAlchemy with pymssql?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pymssql

The [pymssql.connect](https://pythonhosted.org/pymssql/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.connect) documentation lists a `timeout` argument, but how do you pipe that through from [SqlAlchemy using a mssql+pymssql:// connection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server)?

Answer (score 2):

Through experimentation, it must be passed as a connection URL query parameter:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

ms_url = f"mssql+pymssql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}?timeout=10"
ms_engine = create_engine(
  ms_url,
  pool_pre_ping=True,  # any other args
  connect_args={
    # other connect args for example; but timeout does not work here
    "login_timeout": 3,
  },
)
connection = ms_engine.connect()
```

Alternatives did not work:

- Passing `connect_args={"timeout": 10}` does not work, queries longer than 10s still run.
- The `sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect()` call does not accept a `timeout` kwarg.